# Pentaho: Where connections, data, sources and schemas are stored in filesystem?

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to build a Pentaho 8.0 BI Server CE installation inside a Docker container. Despite the installation works very well, I can't figure out where connections, data, sources and schemas are stored in file system.

It would be nice to put those files inside a mounted volume, since files created within container disappear after its shutdown.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in a Jackrabbit repository, in .../pentaho-solutions/system/jackrabbit/

Comment: Thanks. And do you if all the data created during the execution of Pentaho server is store in that place? Is it possible to config other dictory to store that data?